# flip svg coordinate system

Tags: svg, coordinate-systems, cartesian

Is there a way to flip the SVG coordinate system so that [0,0] is in the lower left instead of the upper left?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I have done a lot of experimentation, and the only logical method is as follows:

```
<g transform="translate(0,400)">
<g transform="scale(1,-1)">
```

Where 400 is the height of the image. What this does it move everything down so that the top of the image is now and the bottom of the image, then the scale operation flips the Y coordinates, so that the bit that is now off the page/image is flipped back up to fill the space left behind.

Comment: Do you need the first translate? I've already accomplished that through the `viewbox="-200 -200 400 400"`.

Comment: These operations can be combined on one line.  <g transform="translate(0,100) scale(1,-1)">

Comment: But now the text is upside down.

Comment: You can use a single `matrix` transformation instead of separate `translate` and `scale` transformations. To flip the y-axis, try `<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 400">` (400 being the height of the image).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage what about flipping the x-axis?

Comment: @SashaFonseca `<g transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 400 0)">` (assuming a width of 400)

Comment: @felix how did you fix the upside text problem?

Comment: hmmm if you are coding then you can easily flip it in your code by doing your SVG layer height - y path coordiante

Answer (score 46):

The best all around combo I've found for transforming to a cartesian coordinate system is pretty simple:

**css**

```css
svg.cartesian {
  display:flex;
}

/* Flip the vertical axis in <g> to emulate cartesian. */
svg.cartesian > g {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

/* Re-flip all <text> element descendants to their original side up. */
svg.cartesian > g text {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <svg class="cartesian" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <g>
    <!-- SVG Start -->

    <!-- Vertical / Horizontal Axis: Can be removed if you don't want x/y axes. -->
    <path d="M0 -100 V 200" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" />
    <path d="M-100 0 H 200" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" />
    
    <!-- Plotting: This is an example plotting two points at (20, 20) and (-50, -35), replace it with your data. -->
    <g transform="translate(20, 20)">
      <circle r="1" />
      <text>(20, 20)</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-50, -35)">
      <circle r="0.5" />
      <text>(-50, -35)</text>
    </g>

    <!-- SVG End -->
  </g>
  </svg>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**This will auto-unflip all the text elements on the page via the css `scaleY(-1)`.**

Comment: A bit underrated this answer, it seems to me.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I wrote this down. I refer back to it whenever I need to do this. I just updated with comments explaining what the parts do so it's easier to use.

Comment: This could use more explanation. Got it working but not trivially. I would add some, but don't understand it all yet...

Comment: @Tony - I added more information to the comments. Let me know whats confusing specifically and I'll try to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added a couple comments to the CSS, I think it's pretty understandable now.

Comment: It looks like your comments got rejected by others. I paraphrased but kept condense since a lot of text becomes overwhelming.

Comment: Fixed the CSS comments so they don't break the snippet.

Comment: My bad, did this quick. Thanks @RickTeachey

Comment: Coming at this very late, but could you put the class on the group element, just in case you wanted other nested groups?

Answer (score 14):

I know this is old, but I was doing the same thing, tried @Nippysaurus version but this is too annoying since everything will be rotated (so if you put images, you'll have to rotate them back). There's another solution though

What I did was simply move the viewBox of the `svg` and invert all coordinates on the y axis (and removing the height of the object to be at the bottom left corner on it too), like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="300" viewBox="0 -300 200 300">
  <rect x="20" y="-40" width="20" height="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"></rect>
</svg>
```

this will put a `rect` at 20,20 from the bottom left corner of the `svg`, see http://jsfiddle.net/DUVGz/

Comment: At first sight this seems a kludge, however, having tried all of the other solutions, I have to agree with @Guillaume that all of the `transform` solutions are a PIA due to the effect on text, etc..., so this is the solution I've adopted for SVG output.

Comment: But how will transformations inside transformations fan out? Ie. nested groups ...

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know the size of the svg than you can use CSS transformations for the whole SVG element:

```
#parrot {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* center of rotation is set to the center of the element */
    transform: scale(1,-1);
}
```

Credits:
https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/#transforming-svgs-with-css

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a coordinate rotation of -90 followed by a translation of + the height of your new figure should do it. There is an example at [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ExampleRotateScale).

Comment: I think what you had in mind is a rotate 180, followed by a translation of -w and -h. This does not work, [0,0] is still at the top left.

Comment: I suspect that your SVG implementation is non-conformant which isn't surprising for a (presumably) rarely used feature. An affine rotation of -90 moves the Cartesian quadrant IV (+x, -y) into quadrant I (+x, +y). A rotation of 180 degrees would put your reference frame into quadrant II with the origin in the lower left. The reason your self-answer works is that it is congruent to my original answer but likely uses better tested bits of your SVG interpreter of choice. Personally, I'd just calculate the affine transformation in my user-space code and be pessimistic about SVG capabilities.

Comment: You are probably right. I am using Safari on OS X 10.6, so will test it on a Windows machine tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

```
<g transform="translate(0,400) scale(1,-1)">
```

which also  equivalent to below

```
<g transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-400) ">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [matrix()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix)

> `<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 svgHeight)">`

because

`matrix(a b c d e f)` as below

```
| a c e |
| b d f |
| 0 0 1 |
```

(x,y)

```
| x |
| y |
| 1 |
```

matrix(a b c d e f) ． (x,y)

```
| a c e |    |x|    | ax+cy+e |
| b d f | ． |y|  = | bx+dy+f | 
| 0 0 1 |    |1|    | 0x+0y+1 |
```

when

```
a, b, c,  d, e, f          
1, 0, 0, -1, 0, heght
=>
| ax+cy+e |    | x           |
| bx+dy+f |  = | -y + height |
| 0x+0y+1 |    | 1           |
```

### Example

```html
<style>
  svg {
    border: 1px solid
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>org</th>
    <th>svg</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>top left</td>
    <td>
      <svg width="100" height="100" stroke="black">
        <path d="
      M 50 70
      L 80 30
      "/>
        <circle fill='#ff0000' cx="50" cy="70" r="2"></circle>
        <text x=55 y=75 style="font-size: 10px;" fill="blue">(50, 70)</text>
        
        <!-- x -->
        <!-- https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ -->
        <polygon points="30 7 10 15 10 0" fill="gray" />
        <!-- y -->
        <polygon points="15,20 0,20 7 40" fill="gray" />
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>bottom left</td>
    <td>
      <svg width="100" height="100" stroke="black">
        <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 100)"> <!--  -->
          <path d="
      M 50 70
      L 80 30
      "/>
          <circle fill='#ff0000' cx="50" cy="70" r="2"></circle>

          <!-- x -->
          <polygon points="30 7 10 15 10 0" fill="gray" />
          <!-- y -->
          <polygon points="15,20 0,20 7 40" fill="gray" />
        </g>
        <!-- y=-75+100=25 -->
        <text x=55 y=25 style="font-size: 10px;" fill="blue">(50, 70)</text>
      </svg>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is to use D3 v4 [scaleLinear](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#linear-scales) to create a function that will do the swapping for you.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";

...

// Set the height to the actual value to where you want to shift the coords.
// Most likely based on the size of the element it is contained within
let height = 1; 
let y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,1])
  .range([height,0]);

console.log("0 = " + y(0));       // = 1
console.log("0.5 = " + y(0.5));   // = 0.5
console.log("1 = " + y(1));       // = 0
console.log("100 = " + y(100));   // = -99
console.log("-100 = " + y(-100)); // = 101
```

See [runable code via tonic](https://tonicdev.com/baerrach/tonic-npm-d3-scale)

Answer (score -2):

What I did normally is drawing/putting the coordinate at the negative value of y-axis on the cartesian plane. Later on transfer the coordinate by replacing the negative value of y-axis into positive value.

Answer (score -7):

I think the simpliest way to rotate element for 180 deg is that you rotate for 180.1 deg;

transform="translate(180.1,0,0)"

Comment: translate takes only two arguments, i.e., x and y coordinates. I don't think it takes in 3D coordinates (x,y,z). If you are intended to use 3D coordinates, then you have to use translate3d() which takes 3 coordinates. Take a look at the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate